# Whitespace in stack snippets removed

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, whitespace

I was just [answering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44289388/is-non-breaking-space-always-treated-like-whitespace-in-javascript-source) a question asking about allowed whitespace in JavaScript code and included example code. This code snippet includes spaces, form-feeds (U+000C), line-tabulations (U+000B).

**Snippet before saving:**

[image]

While it worked well in the stack snippet code editor, as soon as I saved my answer, most of the non-space whitespace characters (form-feed, line-tabulation etc.) where removed and the snippet now throws an error.

**Snippet after saving:**

[image]

This is the original code I'd like to include in my answer: https://pastebin.com/1XFLfddv

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I'm doubting that this is a bug; no one would ever expect you to use any other spacing character to add spaces besides...space.

Comment: @Makoto Even in string literals? Also, I expect my code to still run after saving an answer when it runs in and after closing the stack snippet editor.

Comment: Some pre-processing of the snippet has to happen, but it's a fair point that string literals wouldn't be expected to be touched.